# How to get more control over Freestyle external contour lines

Tags: freestyle

I'm looking for a way to get Freestyle to render just the outline lines around objects.  Using inclusive + logical Or + external contour seems to do what I want when rendering objects over a transparent background. But in the picture below, I'd like for the cube that occludes the plane to still have the external contours of it drawn around all the way around the cube.

[image]

Any ideas on how to get those missing freestyle lines rendered?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to go into Edit Mode > Select all Edges > Edge > Mark Freestyle Edge
Now you have to go into the "View Layer Properties" and untick everything besides "Edge Mark" under the "Edge Types" Option.
This should do the Trick.