# Any way I can remove everything except the outline?

Tags: edges, freestyle

Exactly like the question says. I'm using the freestyle tool. Is there any way to remove all the faces in this image and just keep the outline. Either in edit mode or rendering? Or do I need to learn how to use Photoshop or some kind of image editor?

I tried marking freestyle edge like it says here, but that didn't give me the affect I wanted.
[How to get more control over Freestyle external contour lines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175025/how-to-get-more-control-over-freestyle-external-contour-lines)

I also tried deleting just the faces and keeping the edges, but then nothing displays when the image is rendered.

[image]

Comment: a simple solution would be: go into edit mode, press a to select all faces. then press i twice to inset individual faces. delete the selcted faces. or use a wire modifier to get the frame of a object.

Comment: Consider a transparent material with no specular shine.

Comment: The compositor can also make areas transparent.  I have not tested the idea with Freestyle.

Comment: One of the answers to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170301/35559) may do it for you.